# How to remove background default color of next.js latest

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, styles

[Here is the screenshot of the issue](https://ibb.co/Z6jsR26)

When i change any gradient color it default give these lines on next.js but the problem is solved when i give any blue or green color

My current color code of bg when i add this then i got the above ss problem

```
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #02071D 0%, rgba(2, 7, 29, 0) 100%, rgba(2, 7, 29, 0.6) 100%);
```

How to fix this ?

answer to solve my styling in bg

Answer (score 0):

apply like this in your globals.css file.

```
 body,html{
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #02071D 0%, rgba(2, 7, 29, 0) 100%, rgba(2, 7, 29, 0.6) 100%);
}
```